# Parameters to control the size of a spectrogram

Tags: python, signal-processing, spectrogram, librosa

I am trying to get the spectrogram as described by the following instruction.

> Each audio segment has duration of 5s. Frames with equal size are
>   extracted from the audio (with overlap between the consecutive frames), and each of the frame consists of 1024
>   samples. The mel-scale is divided into 128 bins. Therefore, the
>   spectrogram for the audio segment has the dimension of 192×128.

To my knowledge, this instruction implies `n_mels=128` and `n_fft=1024` in the `melspectrogram`  function. So I tried to get a spectrogram with the following code:

```
from librosa import load, power_to_db
from librosa.display import specshow
from librosa.feature import melspectrogram

audio_path = r'5s.wav'
y, sr = load(audio_path,sr=44100)
S = melspectrogram(y,sr,n_mels=128,n_fft=1024,hop_length=512)
print(S.shape)
```

The shape of `y` is `(220500,)` and the sampling rate `sr` is `44100` And the spectrogram shape I get is `(128, 431)`. The `128 mel-scale` size is correct, yet the number of frames I get is `431` instead of `192` frames mentioned in the instruction.

In order to get 192 frames, I changed the sampling rate to `22050` and keep adjusting the `hop_lenght`until the spectrogram has `192` frames:

```
audio_path = r'5s.wav'
y, sr = load(audio_path,sr=22050)
S = melspectrogram(y,sr,n_mels=128,n_fft=1024,hop_length=575)
print(S.shape)
```

However, I am not sure if it is the correct way to get the spectrogram dimension that I want. It seems the process is just trial and error. I wonder if there is a more scientific way to get a spectrogram with the shape that I want without guessing the parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

If you divide your `y_shape` length by the `hop_length` -- you'll get the number of the frames:

```
220500 / 512 = 430.6
```

If you need 192 frames, input `193 * 512 = 98816` samples in `y`.

Comment: I thought `hop_length` means the number of samples skipped to get the starting point of next window. And it seems your calculation doesn't work for the second code. Since I have `110250` samples this time, and my hop_length is `564`. By using your calculation `110250/564 = 195.5`, the number of frame is not 192.

Comment: @RavenCheuk if you have N samples and slide a window over those samples skipping K samples every time, how many times you'll be able to slide the window?